# How can I make a virtual router on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, sharing

I have a 3G stick that I'm connected with to the network. I would like to share this connection with my PlayStation 3. How can I create a virtual router?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Comment: @Denwerko: you might want to make this an answer.

Comment: @Roland Taylor didn't wanted to post just a link, but it isn't problem probably...

Comment: @Denwerko: you can add the relevant details (even copy and paste) to your question. Just use a quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

As many times mentioned, you can read how to share network connection here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

if it wont help, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

just type

```
sudo apt-install hostapd
```

Then you can configure pass and name of SSID as you want at /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf. but you must at least have a hotspot-able wifi-chip(wifi-card) on your motherboard. Vender like Broadcom(in my case bit old Machintosh) doesn't have the one, so not in use as hotspot but simply as accessing other wifis. you can google a list of which vender's wifi-card can be used as hotspot(^O^)Y just check your wifi vender ID by typing in my case

```
lspci -vnn -d 14e4:
```

or

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Secondly, fix Interface by typing
sudo vi /etc/network/interface
or if you are on newer version like Ubuntu 18.04, type

```
sudo vi /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

then

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-network.service
```

next, need to stop /etc/network/interface(NetworkManager), by typing

```
sudo systemctl disable networking
```

check if interface is properly working, type

```
sudo systemctl is-enabled systemd-networkd.service
```

and (enable) should appear if all good.
then, type

```
rfkill list all
```

if you get error saying ....soft blocked..., type

```
rfkill unblock wifi
```

then,type

```
sudo ip link set wlp2s0 up
```

then, check the interface name for wifi, by typing

```
ifconfig -a
```

the name allocated to your wifi interface is(mostly wlp2s0 not those like ens7 or enther9...) 
then finally type

```
sudo netplan apply
```

(oUo)Y----have fun !!!!